# How does the server/client action work?

Tags: sockets

I'm not sure where and how to start, but I have a couple questions about the way how server and client(s) work with each other. I'm quite new to Java and any programming, so I'm pretty much clueless. These questions are about multiplayer games such as Minecraft, WoW etc.

So let me get started.

1. The first thing I'd like to know is how does the interaction work in the first place? I've read a documentation about this, and it told me to use a Socket, then a PrintWriter and BufferedReader for input and output.
2. (related to 1.) What if someone if smart enough to decompile the client, then edit the sent data to e.g change the position values, and when the server receives the data, it would reposition the player to wherever they set their new location. How can I prevent this?
3. What is the real/best way to do the server/client interaction? Do I use a Socket and write stuff in it for clients to receive, or should I use a DatagramSocket and DatagramPacket? Or is there another way?

I'm wanting the server to be separated from the clients, just like in almost every other multiplayer game: you have a file that starts a server, then clients can connect to that.

Thanks in advance, I'd love to know the concept of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This is overly broad and can't be reasonably answered in a form acceptable for this site. I recommend you keep reading tutorials and trying to write small test programs till you get it figured out

2. Yes a lot of "cheat clients" do exactly what you are describing. The only way to stop it is on the server side it must validate the information comming in from a client (if a player's max speed is `x` check if `newLocation > oldLocation + x` and if it is kick the player off the server for cheating). However the problem is that is the more you check the more CPU time that takes up. You need to balance cheat protection with server performance

3. You need to develop a "Message protocol", sockets are just streams of bytes. When you are on the other end of the communication you have no way to tell the diffrence where one "Message" stops and the next begins unless both sides agree on a standard.

A common message protocol is before you send a message you send a `byte` saying say *what kind* of message you are about to send. Your code will then look something like this (Sorry for the C# I know you said you only know Java)

```
private void ReadIncomingClientData(NetworkStream clientStream)
{
    while((messageLength = clientStream.ReadByte()) != -1)
    {
        switch(message[0])
        {
             case 0:
                 HandlePlayerMovement(clientStream);
             case 1:
                 HandlePlayerChat(clientStream);
             case 2:
                 HandlePlayerBeginLogoff();
             default:
                 throw new InvalidDataException();
        }
    }
}
```

Then within each of those function they each know how many bytes should come next in the message. You mentioned Minecraft, [here is the message protocol it uses](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Classic_server_protocol) so you can see what a more complex one looks like.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. I'll keep looking at networking tutorials and whatnot.